# What is the best way to use front libraries in symfony2

Tags: symfony, libraries, assetic

For example, if I want to use Twitter bootstrap 3 in a Symfony 2 project without using a bundle (and of course, without using a CDN). What is the best way to do that ?

There is a better solution than using an output attribute of stylesheet tag in Twig ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my project, I decided to use `bower` frontend package manager. I can specify required libs(bower.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4",
    "font-awesome": "~4.3.0",
    "jquery" : "~2.1",
    "markup" : "https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js.git",
    "js.class" : "~2.5",
    "bootstrap-select" : "~1.6"
}
```

And directory to download(.bowerrc):

```
{
  "directory" : "web/components"
}
```

And `$ bower install` will download your dependencies to specified folder. In template files I link such resources directly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" media="screen">
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot.